# Power Two SATA Drives with One Molex

Tags: hard-drive, power, splitter

Can I safely power two hard drives ([Western Digital VelociRaptor WD30000HLFS 10k RPM](http://www.cdw.ca/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=1555110&ContractID=0)) from a single molex connection using a [LP4 molex to 2 SATA splitter](http://www.cdw.ca/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=788203&ContractID=0)? The machine's power supply can easily handle the total power requirements of the rig, but I'm unsure of running two **faster, 10k RPM** drives off a splitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In the days when everyone wanted me to put neon lights everywhere, I used quite a few splitters. If you want to use a lot of splitters and extras, try to spread it around e.g. don't have an extension off an extension when there is another one just going straight to a optical drive. - put one on each.

But anyway, these sort of adapters are perfectly safe. I have even used Star tech ones as well. I had no idea they were an international company!

Answer (score 3):

In a word, yes. I'm using a 'DIY' MOLEX splitter for three SATA drives with no problems.

*Based on this concept:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe. You should only worry when you begin to put Molex splitters into Molex splitters. I noticed that my 350W PSU couldn't start the PC with 20 HDDs.

Comment: Is that sarcasm, or did you really attempt 20 HDDs?

Comment: Oh, the server does have 20 HDDs, though now it has two PSUs. The previous incarnation of said server had 27 HDDs (though total capasity after RAID was only 3.5TB).